# Renderer component column grid in Sencha ExtJs 5.1.0

Tags: extjs, renderer

I has problem about renderer, I use renderer to create `numberfield` in `column` of `grid`, but it doesn't work, please see code and help me where I wrong.

```
 xtype:'gridcolumn',
 header: 'Quantity',
 dataIndex: 'qty',
 hideable: false,
 sortable : true,
 renderer:function(value) {
         var id = Ext.id();           
         var numberField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Number', {
              height:100,
         }); 
         return '<div id="' + id + '"></div>';
 }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking at the [Cell Editing plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing). In the code above you are creating an instance of a number field but not actually applying it to anything.

The cell editing plugin allows you to use field components such as text field, number field etc in a column and helps manage edited data.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ns4)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Lisa',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224',
                number: 0
            }, {
                name: 'Bart',
                email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1234',
                num: 1
            }, {
                name: 'Homer',
                email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1244',
                num: 2
            }, {
                name: 'Marge',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1254',
                num: 3
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                header: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                editor: 'textfield'
            }, {
                header: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            }, {
                header: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }, {
                header: 'Number',
                dataIndex: 'num',
                editor: 'numberfield'
            }],
            selModel: 'cellmodel',
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1
            },
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Haiz, I used to using the same way, but if you want show numberfield, you must click in cell, but I want not click to cell and numberfield always show. So, I using renderer for create numberfield also for this reason.